# Java Prime Numbers Client/Server

Tags: java, sockets

I am making an application that tells you if the number you enter is prime or not.The problem I have is that it only asks once and terminates the program. 
How could I do to keep asking numbers and the program ends when enter the number 0?

Updated Code.

```
public class numerosPrimos {

    public static String CheckPrimo(int numero){
        int contador = 0;
        int residuo = 0;
        int divisores = 0; 

        for (contador=1;contador<=numero;contador++)
          {
                residuo=numero%contador;
                if(residuo==0)
                {
                    divisores++;    
                }
          }
        if(divisores>=3)
          {
            return "El numero "+numero+" no es primo";

          }
          else
          {
            return "El numero "+numero+" es primo";

          }
        }
      }
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: I thought some sample would help you, but I am not here to do your work ;)

Comment: @Theolodis I dont was searching that you do my work, anyways Thank you.I dont know why you delete the post, Now I dont have an example for look.

Comment: What is the problem currently?

Comment: @KorayTugay I put the new num, say me if its prime or not, but the second one it stay as "Conecting...".

Comment: I think it is because "server = new Socket("localhost", 1234);" is in your while loop. You do not need this. OR accept your client in a new Thread: socket.accept();

Comment: @KorayTugay It should work if I put it outside the while loop?

Comment: @devtreat Why don't you try?

Comment: @KorayTugay I updated my code now. Everything works ok, but now every number that I type says me that its not prime.

Comment: @devtreat :) debug your code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51486/discussion-between-devtreat-and-koray-tugay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my class, I got all declared as static, I corrected it starting the variables inside "CheckPrimo" like this:

```
public class numerosPrimos {

    public static String CheckPrimo(int numero){
        int contador = 0;
        int residuo = 0;
        int divisores = 0; 

        for (contador=1;contador<=numero;contador++)
          {
                residuo=numero%contador;
                if(residuo==0)
                {
                    divisores++;    
                }
          }
        if(divisores>=3)
          {
            return "El numero "+numero+" no es primo";

          }
          else
          {
            return "El numero "+numero+" es primo";

          }
        }
      }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple said:
Put everything in the main method of the client into a while loop and add an if-branch to jump out of the programm if the given number is 0.

Comment: Yup im done with the Client side, but I think that there is a problem with the server side.

Comment: Yes. You close the server socket. You should not do this. A suggestion: Let the server listen on a specific port. Once the server receives a request, start a new asynchronous handler for this request (on another port). This makes also sure that your server can handle more requests at a time.

Comment: Can you explain it with an example please? :/

Comment: I currently have no code available, but take a look at this here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#multi. They show how the server handles multiple request by spawning new asynchronous request handlers.

Comment: I updated my code with the loop and if -branch to jump out but I'm a mess

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific about what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I updated up the new code as you can see when I put the new num, say me if its prime or not, but the second one it stay as "Conecting..."

Comment: Still not sure how you want to work. Either let the server spawn a new handler for each request (in which case your client has to reconnect for each request) or let the server keep up the connection. In this case your client should connect only once to the server (before the loop) and close also only once (after the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a loop into your client program (instead of calling System#exit after just one number)?

And on the server-side, don't close the server socket. If you do, no one can connect anymore.